# Help out our other Spanish language proposals

Tags: discusión

We have a number of other Spanish-language proposals which you can help with:

- I have once again proposed [Superuser in Spanish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/68914/superuser-in-spanish?referrer=-2lLRI28vEcIvgwyv3SPGA2) over at Area 51.  I encourage anyone who feels they could contribute meaningfully to one of the other proposals, to follow and/or commit.
- We also have a [History in Spanish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/68616/history-in-spanish) proposal
- And you can still sign up for [Stack Overflow in Spanish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish?referrer=i2UNs-26fec9zlsUrCq6xg2), which is ready to go live as soon as SE finishes their international features.

Comment: There is another proporsal in Spanish, that need our help [History (in Spanish)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/68616/history-in-spanish)

Comment: @EmilioGort: Thanks, I didn't know about that one.

Comment: SE has been about to finish their international features for months now.  How long?  Meanwhile SO in Portuguese seems to have gone live, without waiting.

Comment: Nunca nos van a dar mas que esto y siempre va estar en beta

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't see in good eyes a Spanish StackOverflow or a Spanish Superuser.

Although I obviously read and write better in Spanish than in English, I prefer the knowledge to be concentrated on one site. When I post a problem, I want english, french, japanese and spanish people to help me. I don't care where they were born, where they live, or which is their native language. My faulty English has never been a problem on any SE site.

It's in my opinion a better situation than having an english, french, japanese and spanish sites.

Comment: That's valid if you speak English. Many people don't.

Comment: I agree with Flimzy, except that I would say it's valid if you read and write English.  Decades ago, I knew plenty of Spanish speakers who could read a technical guide in English, but couldn't carry on a good conversation orally.

Answer (score 0):

### There is a discussion over in SO Meta concerning a community manager for SO in Spanish that is soon to be named.  It looks like this project is about to move into Beta, although this is the first I've heard about that.

Edit a few months later:

Why doesn't Stackoverflow in Spanish move forward the same way Stackoverflow in Portuguese did.  Aren't the language support issues similar?

SO in Spanish has almost 600 people committed.  Would more people help?  How do we get them.