# Catalan Language SE?

Tags: petición-de-funcionalidad, stackexchange

Would any of the members of this site be keen on supporting a [Catalan Language SE proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121280/catalan-language?referrer=dtDAAKoe5Fst0R_wXBVRfg2) on Area 51?

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Catalan Language]

<sub>Apologies if meta isn't the appropriate place for questions like this! I saw [similar Meta posts](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354/help-out-our-other-spanish-language-proposals) about supporting other SE sites in Spanish and thought this might be of interest to some of the members here.</sub>

Comment: Interesting one! I have been thinking about this proposal for years now and had the feeling that it would be difficult to make it happen (Spanish has 100x times more speakers and we struggle to make Beta successful enough; Dutch has 3x times more speakers and failed). In any case, now that you had the idea, let's go for it! We really should advertise it in social networks if we want to have the initial batch of followers.

Comment: How about a "joint venture"? You could propose "Iberian languages" and allow questions about Catalan, Galician, Asturian, Basque and other languages. Example: the [Latin.SE] site allows questions about Latin and Greek.

Comment: We could always extend the remit of this site to include the languages @Charlie mentions. I suppose that might lead to our friends in the south wanting to include Aymara and Quecha.

Comment: This proposal has been deleted.